# Getting error when trying to place order

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, checkout, migration, magento2.2.3

I have migrate magento 1.9.3.1 to magento 2.2.3. Now I am getting error when trying to place with old customers but its working for new customers.

The error is "No such entity with orderId ="

[image]

Anyone familier with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. 
Actually the issue was with PostNL extension who saves addresses 2 times, 1st time they are getting correct value and second they doesn't.

I have fixed it my upgrading their module to latest version.

Now its resolved.